# Firestore database uploading images using react

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am tying to allow a user to upload an image to firebase storage and store a link in the firestore database. When ever an image is selected and the upload button is clicked the image is added to storage but the link is not saved in the database. all that is being stored under the imageURL is an empty string. Everything else writes to the DB fine.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState} from "react";
import { addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, auth, storage } from "../firebase-config"
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

 export function Create({isAuth}) {
    const [foundation, setFoundation] = useState("")
    const [discription, setDiscription] = useState("")
    const [amountRequested, setAmountRequested] = useState("")
    const [date, setDate] = useState("")
    
    const [image, setImage] = useState("");
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");
    

    const handleImageChange = (e) => {
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
          setImage(e.target.files[0]);
        }
      };
    
      const handleImageUpload = async () => {
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image.name}`);
        const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, image);
    
        uploadTask.on(
          "state_changed",
          null,
          (error) => {
            console.error("Error uploading image: ", error);
          },
          async () => {
            const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
            setImageUrl(downloadURL);          
            }
        );
      };

    const donationCollectionRef = collection(db, "donations")
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const createPost = async () => {
        await addDoc(
        donationCollectionRef,{
        foundation, 
        discription, 
        amountRequested, 
        date,
        imageUrl,
        user: {name: auth.currentUser.displayName , id: auth.currentUser.uid },
        
    });
    navigate("/donations");
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isAuth) {
            navigate("/login")
        };

    });

    return <div className = " donationContainer">
        <div className="createDonationPage">
            <h1>Create Donation</h1>
            <div className="inputGP">
                <label>Foundation Name   </label>
                <input 
                onChange = {(event)=> {
                setFoundation(event.target.value);
                }} 
                />
            </div>
            <div className="inputGP">
            <label>Description</label>
                <textarea
                onChange = {(event)=> {
                    setDiscription(event.target.value);
                }} 
                 />
            </div>
            <div className="inputGP">
                <label>Amount Requested</label>
                <input 
                 onChange = {(event)=> {
                    setAmountRequested(event.target.value);
                }} 
                />                
            </div>
            <div className="inputGP">
                <label>Date Needed By</label>
                <input type="date" 
                 onChange = {(event)=> {
                    setDate(event.target.value);
                }} 
                />                
            </div>
            <div className="inputGP">
                <label >Upload Picture</label>
                <input type= "file" onChange={handleImageChange} />
                <button onClick={handleImageUpload}> Upload </button>
                
            </div>
            <div className="App">
                <button className="button" onClick={createPost}> Submit Request</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>;
};

export default Create;
```

I would like for the link to be stored in the firestore DB

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen people use promise.on(), but looks like the async function in in your uploadTask.on() should take a parameter like snapshot and you should call getDownloadURL on snapshot.ref

Something like this:

```
async (snapshot) => {
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
    setImageUrl(downloadURL);
}
```

Hope this helps!